# Don't use config for "links" in "docker_container" if it's not set

Tags: docker, ansible

I am using Ansible with ["docker_container"](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_container_module.html) to deploy a web app to various environments. When the target host is a non-production server I set the "links" option with a variable, e.g.:

```
   links: "{{ var_db_link }}"
```

.. and this works great ... when var_db_link is actually set.

**Problem:** I need to be able to leave this unset when deploying to a production host because in that case the DB is never going to be a linked container. I was expecting that if was not set that Ansible would ignore the "link" option and not try to use it. Instead it uses the unset value which produced the error: *FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Error creating container: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (\"{\"message\":\"Could not get container for \"}\")"}*

**Question**: Is this even possible? (can Ansible be told to not try to use an option when it has no value set) .. or .. should I (unfortunately) create separate roles / playbooks for each situation (i.e. with "links" option set and without it.

Comment: I've tried setting var_db_link to `null` and even tried, as a kludge, to simply have the container link to itself by setting var as `<the-app-container-name>:self`

Comment: According to [this commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/5637/files#diff-c2983e7efb083bc8a8ce86d6b1bcd059R83) the default value for "links" is null so I tried setting it to null conditionally as follows: `links: "{{ null if var_db_link == '' else var_db_link }}"` which does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

[This line in the referenced commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/5637/files#diff-c2983e7efb083bc8a8ce86d6b1bcd059R84) gives a clue as to the solution:

Instead of trying to set it to null, just set it to an empty list:

```
links: "{{ [] if var_db_link == '' else var_db_link }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want looks like what is described in [Omitting Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html?#omitting-parameters).

You should do :

```
links: "{{ var_db_link | default(omit) }}"
```

You will need Ansible 1.8 or above.